# Using dplyr first and last but ignoring NA values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the below dataframe and I need to ignore the missing value for the last value for id 9.

```
firstlast <- data.frame(id = as.factor(c("01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "04", "04", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09")),
                 var_a = c(13, 21, 32, 33, 44, 21, 33, 35, 17, 18, 21, 22, 17, 13, 33, 32, NA))
```

The df looks like:

```
   id var_a
1  01    13
2  01    21
3  01    32
4  01    33
5  01    44
6  04    21
7  04    33
8  05    35
9  05    17
10 05    18
11 05    21
12 05    22
13 09    17
14 09    13
15 09    33
16 09    32
17 09    NA
```

My attempt thus far:

```
firstlast <- firstlast %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(var_first = first(var_a)) %>%
  mutate(var_last = last(var_a)) %>%
  mutate(change = var_last - var_first)
```

creates:

```
       id var_a var_first var_last change
   (fctr) (dbl)     (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)
1      01    13        13       44     31
2      01    21        13       44     31
3      01    32        13       44     31
4      01    33        13       44     31
5      01    44        13       44     31
6      04    21        21       33     12
7      04    33        21       33     12
8      05    35        35       22    -13
9      05    17        35       22    -13
10     05    18        35       22    -13
11     05    21        35       22    -13
12     05    22        35       22    -13
13     09    17        17       NA     NA
14     09    13        17       NA     NA
15     09    33        17       NA     NA
16     09    32        17       NA     NA
17     09    NA        17       NA     NA
```

However I need to ignore the missing value for the last NA observation for id 9 and instead use the second to last (or the first observed value). When I include `mutate(var_last = last(var_a), na.rm=TRUE)` at that line, I then get a full column of na.rm = TRUE and not ignoring the NA value.

The end df I am hoping to achieve is...

```
       id var_a var_first var_last change
   (fctr) (dbl)     (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)
1      01    13        13       44     31
2      01    21        13       44     31
3      01    32        13       44     31
4      01    33        13       44     31
5      01    44        13       44     31
6      04    21        21       33     12
7      04    33        21       33     12
8      05    35        35       22    -13
9      05    17        35       22    -13
10     05    18        35       22    -13
11     05    21        35       22    -13
12     05    22        35       22    -13
13     09    17        17       32     15
14     09    13        17       32     15
15     09    33        17       32     15
16     09    32        17       32     15
17     09    NA        17       32     15
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mutate` doesn't have an `na.rm` option, neither does `first()` or `last()` which would be more appropriate here. You can omit missing values yourself with `na.omit`:

```
firstlast <- firstlast %>% group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        var_first = first(na.omit(var_a)),
        var_last = last(na.omit(var_a)),
        change = var_last - var_first
    )
# Source: local data frame [17 x 5]
# Groups: id [4]
# 
#        id var_a var_first var_last change
#    (fctr) (dbl)     (dbl)    (dbl)  (dbl)
# 1      01    13        13       44     31
# 2      01    21        13       44     31
# 3      01    32        13       44     31
# 4      01    33        13       44     31
# 5      01    44        13       44     31
# 6      04    21        21       33     12
# 7      04    33        21       33     12
# 8      05    35        35       22    -13
# 9      05    17        35       22    -13
# 10     05    18        35       22    -13
# 11     05    21        35       22    -13
# 12     05    22        35       22    -13
# 13     09    17        17       32     15
# 14     09    13        17       32     15
# 15     09    33        17       32     15
# 16     09    32        17       32     15
# 17     09    NA        17       32     15
```

As a sidenote, giving `mutate` an `na.rm` argument doesn't make much sense. What `NA` values would you omit? Any rows from any columns used in the calculation? Other inputs? Just the result? How would you fill the removed rows to still have the same values? It's much better to be explicit as above.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but that errors out for me with `Error: Unsupported vector type language`. Maybe a bug...anyway, a slightly-less-pretty workaround: `mutate(var_first = na.omit(var_a)[[1]], var_last = rev(na.omit(var_a))[[1]])`

Comment: Hmm, what version of `dplyr` do you have loaded? Mine is pretty out-of-date at 0.4.3 but I would expect it to work with anything newer. Though `na.omit` does add an attribute which could get in the way.

Comment: Another option would be to replace `na.omit(var_a)` with `var_a[!is.na(var_a)]` as in akrun's answer, which is perhaps more transparent than `na.omit(var_a)[[1]]`

Comment: I'm using version 0.5.0 for the new functions. I should check through the news; there may have been something about attribute handling.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor as that does make sense. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(firstlast)[,  c("var_first", "var_last") := .(var_a[!is.na(var_a)][1], 
       tail(var_a[!is.na(var_a)], 1)), 
                , by = id][, change := var_last - var_first][]
#     id var_a var_first var_last change
# 1: 01    13        13       44     31
# 2: 01    21        13       44     31
# 3: 01    32        13       44     31
# 4: 01    33        13       44     31
# 5: 01    44        13       44     31
# 6: 04    21        21       33     12
# 7: 04    33        21       33     12
# 8: 05    35        35       22    -13
# 9: 05    17        35       22    -13
#10: 05    18        35       22    -13
#11: 05    21        35       22    -13
#12: 05    22        35       22    -13
#13: 09    17        17       32     15
#14: 09    13        17       32     15
#15: 09    33        17       32     15
#16: 09    32        17       32     15
#17: 09    NA        17       32     15
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `dplyr 1.1.0`, `first`, `last` and `nth` include a `na_rm` argument:

```r
library(dplyr)
firstlast %>% 
  mutate(var_first = first(var_a, na_rm = TRUE),
         var_last = last(var_a, na_rm = TRUE),
         change = var_last - var_first,
         .by = id)
```